TypeScript Bug "TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts""
This JSON and ts config file is correct but still getting this error, I tried all the possible solutions here in StackOverflow and with AI also but the bug is might be with node version >= 20 and typescript 5 , now how can  I overcome this shortcoming? I stuck there
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./src/index.ts",
   "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build":"tsc",
    "dev": "nodemon"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "mongoose": "^8.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.17",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/node": "^20.14.2",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5"
  }
},

ts config**your text**
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "importHelpers": true
   
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true
},
"lib": ["esnext"],
  "include": ["src"]
}


How did you "run" your file?

I've seen a similar problem with older versions, so it's not specific to node >= 20 or typescript 5. If you are using a regular node to run your program, note that you can't import a .ts extension from a JS module.

For node >=20 this command is working and for mine this solve  the problem
"start": "node --no-warnings=ExperimentalWarning --loader ts-node/esm src/index.ts",
"dev": "nodemon --no-warnings=ExperimentalWarning --loader ts-node/esm src/index.ts" ,i  see this video in youtube  solve the problem  https://youtu.be/jn370WEIvjs?si=KG4tAFBk_0nGHXqd
